# Delete a ListBox using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to delete the ListBox using VBA. But, I am not able to get it deleted. This is my Code,

```
Sub Del_FListBox()

Dim FListBox As ListBox

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Home").FListBox.Delete

End Sub
```

Kindly share your thoughts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

Worksheets("Home").Shapes("List Box 1").delete